# Simba Mongo ODBC driver: returned data that does not match expected data length

Tags: sql, mongodb, odbc, ssms

We are using Simba Mongo ODBC driver to connect to Mongo database and make sql queries. I tested connection on Linux using isql and was able to perform queries.

When my client tried to connect to Mongo through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio he received the following error:

```
OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'mongo' returned data that does not match
expected data length for column '[MSDASQL].contributorComposite__0__biographicalNote'.
The (maximum) expected data length is 255, while the returned data length is 290.
```

I've never worked with this application. Have you got any idea where I can control expected data length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked Server is very picky about metadata and the data that is returned, in general you're more likely to encounter problems if your defined metadata doesn't match exactly what is expected when using it vs. using other applications.

What's happening in this case is that you're retrieving data with a string column defined. The data in the string column has a length of 290, but the driver is reporting a length of 255. This is because MongoDB doesn't return metadata about the length of any specific field as it is a schema-less data source. The driver instead uses a default for reporting lengths of string columns, which by default is set to 255. You can change this by opening the Configuration Dialog for the DSN, going to the Advanced Options, and changing the Standard string column length from 255 to something larger, like 512. This should allow Linked Server to behave properly unless your data exceeds 512 bytes, in which case you should simply adjust this to a larger appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks. It indeed solved problem with "returned data that does not match expected data length" error. But now I have another error message "Requested conversion is not supported". I suppose it's theme for another topic.

Comment: Hi Tamara, if you contact solutions @ simba.com directly they should be able to help you out with getting any other problems resolved very quickly, including the new problem you're seeing.

Comment: Just a note for others, Linked Server has an 8000 character limit when going through ODBC data sources, if your data exceeds that limit, you must restructure your query to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2020/11/how-to-fix-msg-7347-linked-server-returned-data-that-does-not-match-expected-data-length-for-column.html): One  way to get around this problem is to construct your SQL statement, such as:

```
declare @myStmt varchar(max)
set @myStmt = 'select * from my_collection'
EXECUTE (@myStmt) AT MongoDB_PROD_mydb
```

I did try it myself on a linked SQLite server and it worked but the strange part is that on longer entries the text get cut off somewhat randomly. I have not figured this part out yet - it might have something to do with SQLiteODBC driver I'm using.

But the error of "expected data length" is handled.

Michael