# Weird 'returned data that does not match expected data length for column' error while the expected length is much bigger - SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

In my project I am rebuilding my Access database to an SQL Database. So to do this I am transferring the Access DATA to the SQL Database. I made sure they both have the same structure and the Access fields are modified correctly in the SQL database.

For most of the data this works. 
Except for 1 table. This table gives me the following weird error message:

```
OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' for linked server 'OPS_JMD_UPDATE' returned data that does not match expected data length for column '[OPS_JMD_UPDATE]...[OrderStatus].Omschrijving'. The (maximum) expected data length is 100, while the returned data length is 21.
```

**So here some more information about both the Access and SQL field/column:**

- Access type:  Short text
- SQL type: nvarchar(MAX)
- Access column data in it: Normal letters and `&` `-` `%` `é` `+` `€`
  `.` `,` `:` being the 'not normal ones'.
- A few empty Access records (which is allowed)
- A total of 135314 record in the Access table

Iv'e set the SQL datatype to `nvarchar(MAX)` so that the field can never be to small, this didn't seem to help though..

*The OPS_JMD_UPDATE is the linked Access database

What causes this problem? Is it because some characters aren't allowed or..?

Comment: Possible relation to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215979/problem-with-select-in-mysql-through-odbc-from-microsoft-sql-server or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022535/simba-mongo-odbc-driver-returned-data-that-does-not-match-expected-data-length  The morale to the story here is explicitly cast short text to the desired data type. [MSFT Article](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e) may help

Comment: Tried to cast it and looked at the other questions (thank you for that) but sadly it had no effect. First i tried to set it to the speicifc length of 21, then I tried to cast as follows: `INSERT INTO [OrderStatus](

   [Omschrijving] 
  
)
SELECT 

CAST([Omschrijving] AS nvarchar(100))

FROM [OPS_JMD_UPDATE]...[OrderStatus]`

Comment: Limit the insert to a subset or just a few specific records. or even 1. This will help identify if the problem is with a specific record (data) or the connection/something else then we can examine it closely.

Comment: @xQbert Excellent idea! I did a TOP and DESC to pin out the exact record on which it gives an error. It seems to be just ONE record. The strange thing however is that nothing seems to be wrong with it... It has no value in the column that generates the error.. (like many others). The other fields seem to be fine as well of the specific record.

Comment: I'd say there's a non-display character that doesn't follow the proper encoding.  It will look like a space but it really isn't.  write a select try to replace all spaces with a '' empty string.  Anything left as a "Space" is the data i'm talking about.  from there you can use [ASCII()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) to find out what the Ascii code of that character is and determine what to do with it.  If you don't really care, copy and paste the data to notepad, and then copy and paste as an update back then it should work.  notepad will typically remove the encoding

Comment: `select ascii(replace(FieldName,' ','')) from tableName` (assuming it's only 1 character...) if the value looks to be a null... `SELECT * from tableName where ID = IDinQuestion and fieldName is Null`  if no records, it's not null!  Good luck, this is a common problem in ETL (Extract Transform and Load).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was 1 record that generated the error. I pinned out the exact record with a TOP select and DESC Select and then used the `select ascii replace`to remove the error! Solved thanks to xQbert, once more thank you!