# Getting error while fetching the data via linked server in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am running following query on SQL server 2014 using linked server

```
select contact_faxnumber from [ausnry-sqltest1].elk_uat.dbo.crm_view_contact
```

And getting the following error

> OLE DB provider 'SQLNCLI' for linked server 'ausnry-sqltest1' returned data that does not match expected data length for column '[ausnry-sqltest1].[elk_uat].[dbo].[crm_view_contact].Contact_FaxNumber'. The (maximum) expected data length is 15, while the returned data length is 16.

If I run the same query directly on the linked server then it is working fine.

Please suggest what to do ?

Comment: There's a few existing questions on a theme, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215979/problem-with-select-in-mysql-through-odbc-from-microsoft-sql-server , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022535/simba-mongo-odbc-driver-returned-data-that-does-not-match-expected-data-length , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124518/weird-returned-data-that-does-not-match-expected-data-length-for-column-error?noredirect=1&lq=1 ... not marking as duplicate as none of these deal with SQL Server speaking to SQL Server, but might provide further routes of investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `crm_view_contact` is a view (based on the name)? In which case it sounds like the underlying table schema may have changed but the view hasn't had it's metadata updated, so it thinks a column is 15 chars long, where in reality it's longer.

If this is the case, then the view metadata can be refreshed on the source server with:

```
sp_refreshview [ @viewname = ] 'viewname'
```